# Replace loop with apply function *pply in R

Tags: r

I am working on an insurance database and I need to restate the dates. I created a loop but it takes 4 hours to return a result, which is too long.

Now I'm trying to replace the loop with `*pply` function. Any help at all would be much appreciated.

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
          "V1 V2 V3
            AA 1 4
            AB 3 2
            AB 2 7
            CD 5 1
            CC 1 2
            CC 9 6")
#Loop
for(i in 2:nrow(df)) {
  for(j in 2:ncol(df)) {
    if (df[i,1] == df[i-1,1]){
      df[i,j] <- df[i,j] + df[i-1,j]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should describe your actual problem. I think you don't need a loop at all.

Comment: @Roland : I am working currently on an insurance database and I need to restate the dates. I created a loop that takes 4 hours to return a result. The query is too long the raison why I copied an extract above to simplify the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @jogo : thank you! that's exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

With base `R`you can do:

```
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) ave(x, df$V1, FUN=cumsum))
```

Here is a solution with `data.table`:

```
library("data.table")
setDT(df)
dnew <- df[, lapply(.SD, cumsum), V1]
dnew
#    V1 V2 V3
# 1: AA  1  4
# 2: AB  3  2
# 3: AB  5  9
# 4: CD  5  1
# 5: CC  1  2
# 6: CC 10  8
```

**Data used:**

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE,text=
"V1 V2 V3
 AA 1 4
 AB 3 2
 AB 2 7
 CD 5 1
 CC 1 2
 CC 9 6")
```

using `data.table` you are faster with:

```
library("data.table")
df <- fread(
"V1 V2 V3
 AA 1 4
 AB 3 2
 AB 2 7
 CD 5 1
 CC 1 2
 CC 9 6")
```

... this will give a `data.table` object - so `setDT(...)` is not needed

Comment: Thank you! that's exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: @YouKH if it is exactly what you are looking for, consider marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: Ok. it's done. Thank you!